# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'stdole.StdPicture'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am doing Web Search Add-in with Visual Studio Add-in for search some of texts/errors easily on the Internet. I could do as below yet.

[image: Picture one]

And I want to put pictures in front of the links. For example, I want to put "Stack Overflow" picture in front of the "Stack Overflow" link. So I coded as below but I just could not put a picture. Everything is working.

```
        CommandBarPopup oPopup = (CommandBarPopup)
            oCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);
        oPopup.Caption = "Web Search";

        oPopup.BeginGroup = true;

        var webSearchURLs = new[]
        {
            new {name="Google", imageUrl="../images/azizyilmaznet.ico", Url="http://www.google.com/search?q=" , Seq=1},
            new {name="MSDN", imageUrl="../images/azizyilmaznet.ico", Url="http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?query=" , Seq=2},
            new {name="Code Project", imageUrl="../images/azizyilmaznet.ico", Url="http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=" , Seq=3},
            new {name="Stack Overflow", imageUrl="../images/azizyilmaznet.ico", Url="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" , Seq=4},
            new {name="Yahoo", imageUrl="../images/azizyilmaznet.ico", Url="http://search.yahoo.com/bin/search?p=" , Seq=5},
            new {name="Bing", imageUrl="../images/azizyilmaznet.ico", Url="http://www.bing.com/search?q=" , Seq=6},
            new {name="Ask", imageUrl="../images/azizyilmaznet.ico", Url="http://www.ask.com/web?q=" , Seq=7}
        };

        CommandBarButton oControl;
        foreach (var item in webSearchURLs)
        {
            oControl =
            (CommandBarButton)oPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, item.Seq, true);
            oControl.Caption = item.name;

            // Error on below line
            oControl.Picture = item.imageUrl;

            oControl.Tag = item.Url;
            oControl.TooltipText = "Search " + item.name + " for...";
            oControl.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(oControl_Click);
        }
```

This is my error code: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'stdole.StdPicture'.
I didn't convert type string to stdole.StdPicture. What do I do? Is 'oControl.Picture = item.imageUrl;' line wrong? or Should I do string type for imageUrl? or something else?

Comment: The variable `imageUrl` is a string.  You're trying to assign it to a `Picture`.

Comment: you need to load the image from the url into an appropriate object, then assign it.